# Why is Chrome 65 6x slower than other browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, easeljs

My JavaScript app used to perform basically the same in all browsers, but suddenly now on Chrome 65 on MacBook my JavaScript app runs verryy slowly, up to 6 times slower. I compared it to IE, Firefox and Safari running on MacBook and Windows 7. This may be strictly an issue with Chrome 65: the app runs fine using Chrome 63 on Windows 7. Runs fine on iPhone 6 using the Chrome browser.

It's an animation app using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with the EaselJS library added in. Nothing too complicated, user clicks 'start' and off it goes. No user data is used, runs the same code pretty much in the same way every time.

All was fine until I unplugged and went away starting in mid-February. When I returned last week I saw the results you see in the 2-minute YouTube video at this address. I get no errors, it’s just slow.

[2-minute demo of the problem](https://youtu.be/qsAKJNdkXTg)

What’s different about Chrome 65?
Any ideas/suggestions on how to pursue this? (I can pull the app apart, rebuild it and solve whatever the current issue is...but can I trust Google to not throw me another curve ball down the road with Chrome 66, or 70, or 85?)

Comment: You're not really describing the problem in a way that we can reproduce and help you with. You're going to have to dig into this on your own until you can come up with a minimal example that we can see the problem manifest in.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on the same version of Chrome on the same platform. Do you have any extensions installed? Profile your code with Chrome's developer tools and see what's taking so much time.

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=823440

Chrome 65 specifically seems to have performance timing issues on some hardware where it fails to take advantage of the hardware properly. We're (the EaselJS team) already working with them about the issue.

Comment: I've tested this issue against other MacBooks and see it is specific to my computer. Note the issue first appeared after using unsecured hotel WiFi on a trip to South Asia. How do I diagnose, fix it?